# Start node server with .bat file

Tags: node.js, batch-file, gruntjs

I want to start a node server with a `.bat` file, because everytime I start it, a grunt task has to be run. I tried the following lines in the `start.bat`:

```
grunt build
node index.js
```

When I execute it, it just runs the `grunt build` command and then stops. If I delete the `grunt build` command it runs the `node index.js` just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with `call` like so

```
call grunt build
node index.js
```

Comment: why don't I need the `call` on `node index.js`?

Comment: The "problem" is because `grunt` is another batch file which causes the "root" batch file to stop when it exits. As node is not a batch file but an .exe you don't need it

Answer (score 2):

If you tie the commands together with && it will make sure the first is run and then the second.
`grunt build && node index.js`
If you want them to be on separate lines still, a carrot will remove newlines.

`grunt build &&^
node index.js`

Comment: Looking at this again, this solution is more of a hack than anything. I believe DAXaholic's answer is the more correct way to accomplish this.

Comment: Even though it's a hack it works better, because you don't have to confirm the abortian of the program. And it feels like it's a bit quicker.